# What is Subject.asObservable good for?

Tags: rx-java

Why does RxJava need `asObservable`?

Technically each Subject is already an Observable. What is the advantage of it over just casting it like

```java
Observable obs = subject;
```

Comment: Javadoc provides some answer on your question: `This is useful, for instance when you have an implementation of a subclass of Observable but you want to hide the properties and methods of this subclass from whomever you are passing the Observable to.` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Encapsulating with AsObservable: http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/09_SideEffects.html#AsObservable

Comment: I read the documentation before. But what is the benefit over just returning the super class as type?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you were to just cast the `Subject` to an `Observable` then you could still use it as a `Subject` by casting it back:

```java
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
Observable<String> observable = subject;
((PublishSubject<String>) observable).onNext("Hello, world!");
```

`Observable.asObservable()` doesn't actually cast the type to `Observable`; it actually wraps the current `Observable`. That means that no one has access to the upstream `Observable`.

The same code using `asObservable()` crashes with a `ClassCastException`:

```java
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.subscribe(System.out::println);
Observable<String> observable = subject.asObservable();
((PublishSubject<String>) observable).onNext("Hello, world!");
```

It's a lot like the `final` modifier. Sometimes you don't want code to have 100% control over everything.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to "remember" the emitted value for subsequent Subscribers to use, so I used a BehaviourSubject. I chose to return an Observable so that Subscribers didn't try to send data to it.

Comment: I do not want to discuss why it is better to pass an interface over an implementation, I want to know what the benefit is of not just casting it as it inherits from Observable.