# Angular 2 custom Http service ( on every request )

Tags: javascript, http, angular, angular2-services

What I want to achieve is to handle somehow every Http request I'm making and on every request change my variable state. So I made my custom Http service that wraps Angular 2 Http service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
  public isLoading: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.isLoadingHttp(true);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }  

  isLoadingHttp( state: boolean ): void {
    this.isLoading = state;
  }
}
```

So I have `isLoading` **variable** and `isLoadingHttp` **function**.

**First question** - Basically, on **GET** method started I'm setting variable to **true**, but how do I know when request has made and response is ready?

**Second question**: Do I need to make `isLoading` and Observable? I want to access it from my AppComponent and manipulate when to display loader whenever it has changed.

Comment: Yes, you may want to add isLoading$ observable (most likely a subject) as well, because it makes sense here. It probably should be a separate service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
  private _isLoading: number = 0;

  public get isLoading () {
    return this._isLoading;
  }

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this._isLoading++;
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .finally(_ => this._isLoading--);
  }  
}
```

There can be more than one active request at a time.

The `finally` operator needs to be imported like any other operator.

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
  private requestCounter: number = 0;
  private isLoading: Subject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(requestCounter);
  public readonly isLoading$:Observable<number> = this._isLoading.asObservable().share();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.isLoading.next(++this.requestCounter);
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .finally(_ => this.isLoading.next(--this.requestCounter));
  }  
}
```

of if you don't care how many outstanding request there are, but just if there are any

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientService {
  private requestCounter: number = 0;
  private isLoading: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public readonly isLoading$:Observable<boolean> = this._isLoading.asObservable().share();

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();

    this.requestCounter++;
    if(this.requestCounter == 1) {
      this.isLoading.next(true);
    }
    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    })
    .finally(_ => {
      this.requestCounter--;
      if(this.requestCounter == 0) {
        this.isLoading.next(false));
      }
    })
  }  
}
```

Comment: how can I observe ``_isLoading`` ?In my AppComponent I initialize it like this ``isLoading: number = this._http.isLoading;`` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can use for example `<div *ngIf="_http.isLoading">` to let Angular change detection update the view depending on `isLoading` or alternatively (usually a better approach) to use a `BehaviorSubject` and subscribe to it. I'll update my answer to demonstrate it.

Comment: I'm getting this error (Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'Subject<boolean>) on this line  : ``this.isLoading.emit(true);``

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up `emit` with `next`. `emit` is from `EventEmitter`. I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you a lot. Could you just explain a little bit more on this lines: ``private isLoading: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public readonly isLoading$:Observable<boolean> = this._isLoading.asObservable().share();`` . Looks like some Voodo magic :)

Comment: It's similar to what is used in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142968/what-is-subject-asobservable-good-for (especially "That means that no one has access to the upstream Observable.") - it's just some basic encapsulation to hide implementation details from users of your API.